# Clicking items on listview which populates detainfo on a second page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with a search engine which calls a stored procedure to a database. The page contains a listview which is populated based on what the user enters in the search box. I was able turn each item in the listview as links to direct the user to a second page (which contains nothing at the moment). I wanted to be able to click on an item and be directed to second page which contains detailed info about the item.

For example, say I have a database of musicians in one column and their biography in second column. The user searches a musician on the first page and the listview is populated with names of the musicians only. The user clicks on the musician's name and is then directed to the second page which contains their bio(from the database). My questions is how I do populated the second page with detailed info when the user clicks on the item in the listview? Would the click event have to pass parameters back to the database and know to get this specific summary to populate the second page? Would parameter query would be right option for this?

I am sure its a pretty simple thing to do, but I am pretty new to asp.net and no clue how to go about this. Any ideas or methods on how to approaches would be greatly appreciated. I dont have much code on this, since I have been doing most of this in design view and html.

Thanks so much for your time,

Answer (score 1):

A very direct way to do this would be to add a parameter to the link in each item in the list.  So instead of something like this:

```
<a href="detailspage.aspx">View Details</a>
```

You'd have something like this:

```
<a href="detailspage.aspx?id=123">View Details</a>
```

Naturally, each `id` would be different for each row.  How you populate that depends on how you populate the listview.

Then you'd have a single `detailspage.aspx` (or whatever you call it) which would look for an `id` parameter (check the `Request.QueryString["id"]` value in `Page_Load` for web forms, or have it as a method parameter in MVC) and use that value to fetch the record from the database and display the details.

One thing that's very much worth noting in this case is the need to validate that input before sending it to a database.  You didn't specify how you're accessing the database, so I can only guess.  But, regardless of your data access methodology, the *first* thing you want to do with that `id` value on the details page is to make sure it's a valid value to use for selecting data.

For example, if the identifier in the database is an integer, you'll want to try to parse the value into an actual integer variable (if it's a string by default, which it would be from `Request.QueryString`), returning an error to the page if that fails.  Or if it's a GUID, same process.  Basically, you want to do whatever you can to ensure that the value is safe for the database before even connecting to the database.

More details on SQL injection vulnerabilities [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Hey David, thanks for you help. I used the Request.QueryString in my second page to access the database and pull the details to display on my second page. However, I was only able to do that from by setting the id=2. I was wondering if you would also know how to set the id for each item in a listview. What would you recommend? Thanks for all the help you've been.

Comment: @cbenson: Depends on how you're currently populating the listiew.  Can you update the question to include the list view code (both on the page and in the code-behind), as well as the shape of the data being used to populate it?  Then just mention in a comment here so I'll know there's an update.

Comment: Hey David, I got it work the way I wanted with few minor adjustments:  1) changed stored procedure to access the id as well, so my listview now as the list of names and their id associated with them (i didn't have that before) 2) i used databinder and stringquery   **bold**<asp:Hyperlink runat= "server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Results")%>' NavigateUrl='<%# "Testpage2.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"ID")%>' ID="Link2" />**bold** thanks for all your help

Comment: hi @David i just found your answer and this i sexactly what i was looking for. However i would like to know is the method[2nd answer] correct way[safe from injections].

Comment: @Raghav: At the time of this reading, the other answer on this question is wide open to SQL injection attacks and I *do not* recommend using that code.  The concept is fine in that the "second page" (the one which dynamically displays a record based on the identifier passed in via the URL) would read the URL parameter, fetch a specific record based on that parameter, and display it.  However, the author of that answer is doing so in a very unsafe way.

Comment: @David, thanks a lot sir, can you please point me how to achieve the same. I really have looked a lot and even asked a few places with the answer google it. Please sir just give me a start. Will be really very greatfull.

Comment: @Raghav: Are you just asking how to retrieve a record from a database?  There are many tutorials for doing that.  Additionally, there are many frameworks to help with that.  For example, in the current state of .NET development Microsoft recommends the use of Entity Framework for data access.  I would recommend finding a tutorial to get started on that.

Comment: @David, no sir i want to know how to make it safe from injections i.e.
<asp:Hyperlink runat= "server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Results")%>' NavigateUrl='<%# "Testpage2.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"ID")%>' ID="Link2" /> what is wrong in it.

Comment: @Raghav: The code in that comment doesn't access a database, so it has nothing to do with SQL injections.  The flaw in the other answer's code is in how he builds his `SqlCommand` object.  That's where the injection vulnerability happens.  Notice that he's directly concatenating unfiltered user input into the query.  So a user could enter anything they want on the URL and whatever they enter will be executed against the database.  In the ADO.NET approach in that answer he should be using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

So i finally got it to work!! In case someone is stuck or trying to do the same thing I was aiming for...here is what I did:

This is in my first page:

' NavigateUrl='<%# "Testpage2.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"ID")%>' ID="Link2" />  (Results is my data column and ID is the id associated to them)

Note: I added this in my ItemTemplate AND my AlternateTemplate (not sure why but if i didn't, it would just alternate :S)

Second Page Code Behind:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    SqlConnection SQLconn = new SqlConnection("Connectionstring");
    try
    {

        SQLconn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Column1 FROM Table WHERE D='" + Request.QueryString["id"]
             + "'", SQLconn);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                TextBox1.Text = reader["Column1"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
    }

    finally
    {
        SQLconn.Close();
        SqlConnection.ClearPool(SQLconn);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that the code posted here is *wide open* to SQL injection attacks.  It is *not* recommended that anybody use this code.  The concept is still the same, that a page will accept an identifier as a query string parameter and fetch a record based on that identifier.  However, this code for fetching the record is highly insecure and should not be used.